# @Autowired dependency is null in Groovy class implementing a Groovy interface

Tags: spring, groovy, spring-boot

I am trying to inject a property class into a Groovy based class, but the injected class is null.  I do have another properties class that is being injected into a class that is implementing from Tomcat's Filter interface and that is working fine.

Here is my stacktrace when starting the Spring Boot application:

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stormpathAccountService' defined in file [/Users/jfitzgerald/Projects/parsezilla-api-partner/build/classes/main/com/schoolzilla/api/application/credentials/StormpathAccountService.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.schoolzilla.api.application.credentials.StormpathAccountService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1077)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1022)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:706)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
    at com.schoolzilla.api.Application.main(Application.groovy:18)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.schoolzilla.api.application.credentials.StormpathAccountService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1070)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.createGroovyObjectGetPropertySite(AbstractCallSite.java:254)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.acceptGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:239)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:231)
    at com.schoolzilla.api.application.credentials.StormpathAccountService.<init>(StormpathAccountService.groovy:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
    ... 22 more
```

And here is the code that's giving me issues:

```
@Service
class StormpathAccountService implements AccountService {

//This is where my problem lies
    @Autowired
    StormpathProperties stormpathProperties

    private def logger = LogFactory.getLog(StormpathAccountService)

    private def path = System.getProperty("user.home") + stormpathProperties.apiKeyLocation

//more stuff here...

    }
}
```

Groovy interface being implemented:

```
interface AccountService {
    def createAccount(PartnerAccount account);
    def deleteAccount(PartnerAccount account);
    ApiKey fetchApiKey(PartnerAccount account);
}
```

Properties class:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "stormpath")
class StormpathProperties {
    String apiKeyLocation
    String accountUrl
}
```

And the property names from my application.properties file:

```
stormpath.apiKeyLocation
stormpath.accountUrl
```

And finally my main Application class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableConfigurationProperties
class Application {

    static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run Application, args
    }

}
```

I've looked through some other suggestions such as implementing a Java based interface instead of a Groovy based interface for classloader reasons, but so far that has not worked for me.  I have also tried to change the method of injection to constructor based.  The class is successfully injected, but the actual properties are then null.

I've spent a few days banging my head against the keyboard here, so any further help and/or explanation why it's not working would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: 
Here is the other service that is using AccountService.groovy:

```
@Service
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
class PartnerApplicationService {

    def logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PartnerApplicationService)

    @Autowired
    PartnerApplicationRepository repository

    @Autowired
    CredentialsRepository credentialsRepository

    @Autowired
    PartnerService partnerService

    @Autowired
    AccountService accountService

//lots more stuff...
}
```

Comment: have you any controller class? can you show it?

Comment: I have another service class that is simply making calls to the interface like: accountService.createAccount(account)

the interface is now up there.

Comment: have you injected StormpathAccountService or AccountService in it?(with @Autowired)

Comment: Yep.  Newest edit should show that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't inject the `StormpathAccountService` bean into the controller or another classe which uses it, if not try with injecting it:

```
@Autowired
StormpathAccountService stormpathAccountService;
```

**OR:**
inject the `AccountService` interface in it:

```
@Autowired
AccountService accountService;
```

Comment: Just added the other service which is using the AccountService interface.  It's being @Autowired in already.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I found a solution that works for me.  I wound up manually including the StormpathProperties file as part of the @ComponentScan.  I have no idea why this needed to be explicit where everything else woks with @ComponentScan correctly.